# Process all columns / the entire row in a Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataframe containing a mix of string and numeric datatypes, the goal is to create a new `features` column that is a `minhash` of all of them.

While this could be done by performing a `dataframe.toRDD` it is expensive to do that when the next step will be to simply convert the `RDD` *back* to a dataframe.

So is there a way to do a `udf` along the following lines:

```
val wholeRowUdf = udf( (row: Row) =>  computeHash(row))
```

`Row` is not a `spark sql` datatype of course - so this would not work as shown.

**Update/clarifiction**  I realize it is easy to create a full-row UDF that runs inside `withColumn`. What is not so clear is what can be used inside a `spark sql` statement:

```
val featurizedDf = spark.sql("select wholeRowUdf( what goes here? ) as features 
                              from mytable")
```

Comment: who said Row is not a spark sql.? and your udf funtion is just correct

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  And how would a "full row" be invoked in a `spark sql` statement?   e.g. `select wholeRowUdf( what goes here?? ) from ..`

Comment: just use struct inbuilt function to make all the columns as one and pass to udf function. Its that easy.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  Feel free to make an answer illustrating your point. The way you are expressing in your comments I don't know whether you are implying "it's obvious - *how can you not see this* " or "here is an easy way to do this".

Comment: I have answered below :) please check

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  Your answer does not address my core question: have updated it to clarify.

Comment: I have updated my answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a workaround: drop the column names into any existing `spark sql` function to generate a new output column:

```
concat(${df.columns.tail.mkString(",'-',")}) as Features
```

In this case the first column in the dataframe is a target and was excluded. That is another advantage of this approach: the actual list of columns many be manipulated.

This approach avoids unnecessary restructuring of the RDD/dataframes.

Comment: Coming back to this question years later I think this is a more useful approach

Answer (score 15):

> > Row is not a spark sql datatype of course - so this would not work as shown.

**I am going to show that you can use Row to pass all the columns or selected columns to a udf function using struct inbuilt function**

First I define a `dataframe`

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "b", "c"),
  ("a1", "b1", "c1")
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
//    +----+----+----+
//    |col1|col2|col3|
//    +----+----+----+
//    |a   |b   |c   |
//    |a1  |b1  |c1  |
//    +----+----+----+
```

Then I define *a function to make all the elements in a row as one string separated by `,`* (as you have computeHash function)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
def concatFunc(row: Row) = row.mkString(", ")
```

Then I use it in `udf` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def combineUdf = udf((row: Row) => concatFunc(row))
```

Finally I call the `udf` function using `withColumn` function and `struct` *inbuilt function* combining selected columns as one column and pass to the `udf` function

```
df.withColumn("contcatenated", combineUdf(struct(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("col3")))).show(false)
//    +----+----+----+-------------+
//    |col1|col2|col3|contcatenated|
//    +----+----+----+-------------+
//    |a   |b   |c   |a, b, c      |
//    |a1  |b1  |c1  |a1, b1, c1   |
//    +----+----+----+-------------+
```

So you can see that *Row can be used to pass whole row as an argument*

You can even **pass all columns in a row at once**

```
val columns = df.columns
df.withColumn("contcatenated", combineUdf(struct(columns.map(col): _*)))
```

**Updated**

You can *achieve the same with sql queries* too, you just n*eed to register the udf function* as

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempview")
sqlContext.udf.register("combineUdf", combineUdf)
sqlContext.sql("select *, combineUdf(struct(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)) as concatenated from tempview")
```

It will give you the same result as above

Now if you *don't want to hardcode the names of columns then you can select the column names according to your desire and make it a string*

```
val columns = df.columns.map(x => "`"+x+"`").mkString(",")
sqlContext.sql(s"select *, combineUdf(struct(${columns})) as concatenated from tempview")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I am looking for a construct that supports a  *sql statement*. Will update the OP

Comment: What if we have two dozen columns that may be changing ..  i'd rather not do it the way you showed that hard codes the columns : better to "discover" the column names in some way. If you can provide that then I'll award.

Comment: I had already given you hints in my previous update on choosing variable column names instead of hard codings. Look at my updates I have fulfilled your every challange. :) . What award would you give me for my hard work ;) 25 points ? hahaha. let me know if you have further challanges :P

Comment: My last comment was not answered.

Comment: Oh I did not notice you had updated to include the `combineUdf` . I will upvote as potentially useful. Do you think your approach were simpler than what I had posted?

Comment: It would be the same . I answered just to show you that it is possible to pass Row as a datatype to udf. thats all.

Comment: my  approach/answer was more succint /simple and just as powerful.  but usually i prefer to award to someone else