# Pass Column Object into UDF Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my code block., I want to pass Column to "calculateCredit" but the following code GlobalLock
take value of that column.

```
object CreditHostory {

    def calculateCredit(rows: Row)  = {

    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    sparkSession.udf.register("calcCredit", calculateCredit _)

    callUDF("calcCredit", struct(col("credit") , col("amount")))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some sample data and/or an error message? I'm not sure what you mean by GlobalLock taking the value of the column.

Comment: you should look at my answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/49436338/5880706