# Pass Every Column in a Row into a Hash Function in Spark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with `N` columns, I want to concatenate them all to a string column and then perform a hash on that column. [I have found a similar question in Scala.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434647/process-all-columns-the-entire-row-in-a-spark-udf)

I want to do this entirely inside of Spark SQL ideally, I have tried `HASH(*) as myhashcolumn` but due to several columns being sometimes null I can't make this work as I would expected.

If I have to create a UDF and register it to make this happen, I need to use Python and not Scala as all my other code is in Python.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to generate a hash based on all the columns of a DataFrame dynamically, you can use this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("checksum", F.xxhash64(*df.schema.names))
```

Explanation:
`df.schema.names` is a list with the names of all the columns in the DataFrame `df`. Using a `*` spreads this list into the elements it contains. You can then pass the elements to functions such as [xxhash64](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.xxhash64.html) (for 64-bit hashes) and [hash](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.hash.html) (for 32-bit hashes).

Comment: Note that null columns do not appear to be included in the checksum. ie if you have a checksum for a dataframe, then add a column that has a null value for that new column - the new checksum will match the original dataframe without that column.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code.

```
df.select([hash(col) for col in df.columns]).show()
```

Comment: I think there are two issues with the above snippet. Firstly the above code will provide the hash of each col individually while the requirement is to create a single hash value considering all the cols. Secondly it is using variable name as 'col' which is actually a key word considering the pyspark.sql package. this will result into erroneous result.

i think this should be a better approach

df.select('*',hash(*df.columns)).show()

same is mentioned by @d-to-the-k as wel

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in pyspark likes the following (just pass input columns to the function):

```
new_df = df.withColumn("contcatenated", hash_function(col("col1"), col("col2"), col("col3")))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there to map all columns dynamically? The reason, I'm not listening them inside of my sql is because this doesn't seem possible.